# What are the historical roots of cryptarithmetic?

Tags: arithmetic, math-history

A typical cryptarithmetic is:

```
    S E N D         9 5 6 7
+   M O R E     +   1 0 8 5
-----------     -----------
= M O N E Y     = 1 0 6 5 2
```

On the internet it is said: 
"The invention of Cryptarithmetic has been ascribed to ancient China."
But I don't find some evidence.

The statements sounds dubious to me since 
china doesn't have a letter system. Notwithstanding
problems with ancient position systems. Could
somebody explain?

Comment: The ascription to China isn't *completely* implausible, since the Chinese calculated with a straightforward base-10 system called [rod numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rod_numerals), very similar to the medieval European counting boards, in which it wouldn't be hard to formulate a cryptarithm puzzle. They could use characters in place of letters, and the entire puzzle could be something meaningful.  Whether they actually did so, I have no idea.

Comment: Looks they are called nowadays hukumenzan in Japan. But how about China? I still don't know.

Comment: This is a hukumenzan: http://www.janko.at/Raetsel/Nikoli/Hukumenzan.htm . Somebody told me the translation is "prune and peach are friends", and the script is Hiragana.